# How to hide page numbers but still be able to use them in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

How to hide page numbers in my document and still be able to display them in table of contents?

Obviously, `\pagenumbering{gobble}` does work, but they are no more visible in the table of contents either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Are you using something like [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)?

Comment: Welcome! Is the aim to confuse and frustrate your readers?

Comment: Why you like to inform reader, that it can find something on the page `xy`, but this page number is not presented?

Comment: @Werner I am using `\documentclass{article}`, am not using `fancyhdr`.@Zarko The page numbers must be hidden, as it is an assignment to rewrite a word document in LaTeX and the word document does not have page numbers.

Comment: @Matt: Your assignment is to make a full copy of a Word document?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer Yes, pretty much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there's no special header or footer apparently, I would suggest to use `\pagestyle{empty}`, but as **cfr** and **Zarko** already noted: This is confusing -- does one have to count the pages oneself during reading (either on screen or using a hardcopy?)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\blindtext[10]
\section{Second}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

**Update** Removing the page number from title page as well

The `\maketitle` command uses `\thispagestyle{plain}` explicitly. Redefining `\maketitle` is too much work (or patching as well).
Since pagestyles are defined in `\ps@....` macros, it's easier to use

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
```

i.e. making the `plain` style a copy of `empty`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Theory of Brontosaurs}
\author{Ann Elk (Misses)}

\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{First}
\blindtext[10]
\section{Second}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, `\pagestyle{empty}` seems to work almost as desired, just with one small problem: the title page (made with `\maketitle`) still shows up as number one, is there a way to get rid of that as well?

Comment: @Matt: See the update please!

Answer (score 3):

One simple way to do this is to use `fancyhdr` to clear the page numbers.

```
% in preamble
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % removes the horizontal bar at the top
```

No page numbers are printed on the pages, but the table of contents functions normally.

Note that if you have a title, you need to fix the title page as well, by calling `\thispagestyle{fancy}`.

```
% in document body
\title{Copper, Silver, Gold: An Indestructible Metal Alloy}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

Part of this hinges on the fact that you're using the `article` document class, which has no default header or footer except for the page number. If you wanted to use a different class, such as `amsart`, this would clear the default header, which also contains your title, so you'd want to use `fancyhdr` to put the title back.

If you used a document class with chapters, such as `book`, you'd need to call `\thispagestyle{fancy}` at the start of each chapter, and again, specifics would depend on your document class.